# How to update synonyms in managed resources in solr using java

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm using solr 6.6. I have integrated ManagedSynonymFilterFactory in my solr as specified in the documentation https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/managed-resources.html#ManagedResources-Synonyms

I can update the synonyms using apis specified in that documentation. But I want to upload synonyms from my java application to solr.

(Note: The source may be anything like db or file)

Comment: Have you tried passing in multiple entries in your request? 

For example,
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '**{"mad":["angry","upset"], "happy": ["smiling", "jolly"]}**' "http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/schema/analysis/synonyms/english"

Comment: Yes. I tried and it is working. But, I need to insert all the combination in a single request like {"mad":["angry","upset"], "angry": ["upset", "mad"], "upset": ["angry", "mad"]} and for multiple set. I tried curl -X PUT -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '["funny", "entertaining", "whimiscal", "jocular"]' "http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/schema/analysis/synonyms/english" to achive multiple combination. But I couldn't insert mutiple set in this way.

Comment: Okay, if  `{"mad":["angry","upset"], "angry": ["upset", "mad"], "upset": ["angry", "mad"]}` works then isn't that the answer? 

Looking at your initial question, my understanding is that you are looking to use your Java app to read synonyms from a source (db, file, etc.) and send them to Solr. So just read them, constructed a json object and then do a post to Solr. Why doesn't that work?

Comment: is there a way to do this using the SolrJ client in java? I too am looking for something like this.